# Как в mysql дублировать значения из столбца одной таблицы в другую, при наличии общего столбца?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы: tab1 (id, email, acc и т.д.) и tab2 (id, email и т.д.).
Значение id в этих таблицах это авто инкремент и значения этих колонок разные.
Задача:
сделать запрос который бы брал значение id из tab2 и подставлял его в колонку acc tab1 при условии что в колонке email совпадают данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

соедините таблицы по полю и напишите апдейт

```
 update tab1
 inner join tab2 on tab2.email = tab1.email
 SET tab1.acc = tab2.id
```

Comment: Спасибо, это хорошее решение.